# SmtpServer.EnableSsl=true ;

Tags: c#

I have gone through many example codes on SMTP connection. In those, most people use  `SmtpServer.EnableSsl=true ;` with only gmail (my observation). What is the scope or use of this code?

Comment: If SMTP server you are connecting is required SSL, you must enable it.

Comment: When i try to enable it, code throws exception "Server does not support secure connections.". But i have checked in my outlook settings, its enabled. Am using outlook attached to yahoo mail ID. Is this error because of outlook attached to yahoo mail???

Comment: @RaghuSYadav Maybe you're on the wrong port? Check your settings against the ones listed [here](http://email.about.com/od/accessingyahoomail/f/Yahoo_Mail_SMTP_Settings.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at from *MSDN* for *[`SmtpClient.EnableSsl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx)*;

> Specify whether the SmtpClient uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) to
>   encrypt the connection.

---

> true if the SmtpClient uses SSL; otherwise, false. The default is
>   false. The EnableSsl property specifies whether SSL is used to access
>   the specified SMTP mail server.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN on the `SmtpClient` class, `EnableSSl` property:

- Specify whether the SmtpClient uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) to encrypt the connection.

[Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx).

> The default value for this property can also be set in a machine or
>   application configuration file. Any changes made to the EnableSsl
>   property override the configuration file settings.
>
> The SmtpClient class only supports the SMTP Service Extension for
>   Secure SMTP over Transport Layer Security as defined in RFC 3207. In
>   this mode, the SMTP session begins on an unencrypted channel, then a
>   STARTTLS command is issued by the client to the server to switch to
>   secure communication using SSL. See RFC 3207 published by the Internet
>   Engineering Task Force (IETF) for more information.
>
> An alternate connection method is where an SSL session is established
>   up front before any protocol commands are sent. This connection method
>   is sometimes called SMTP/SSL, SMTP over SSL, or SMTPS and by default
>   uses port 465. This alternate connection method using SSL is not
>   currently supported.
>
> You can use ClientCertificates to specify which client certificates
>   should be used to establish the SSL connection. The
>   ServerCertificateValidationCallback allows you to reject the
>   certificate provided by the SMTP server. The SecurityProtocol property
>   allows you to specify the version of the SSL protocol to use.
>
> **Note:**
>
> If the EnableSsl property is set to true, and the SMTP mail server
>   does not advertise STARTTLS in the response to the EHLO command, then
>   a call to the Send or SendAsync methods will throw an SmtpException.

Answer (score -2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx

Took me two seconds via google...